# How to load balance a connected socket?

Tags: sockets, haproxy, high-availability

I need some help on my problem : I am working in a windows 2019 server environment.
I have a solution in place that require a connected protocol between client and server : a socket is opened on TCP/IP and the client start a session then there is a dialog between the client and the server : the dialog is always initiated by the client. The client act also as a server because it expose a service over internet that require to open and close the socket during a session of pin verification. Here a current logical view of my system in place :
[image]

As there is a need to have a connected socket between my client and my BE Service, I am forced to have an affinity in place : I am searching a way to make ANY of my two clients able to issue commands to my BE service and receive response as if they were connected via a persistent socket. I need a solution that do not introduce a SPOF : for example I was thinking in using a HA PROXY but if there is a problem with it I could loose all my BE services. The question is : is there anyway to put in place a mediator between my clients and my BE services so that any client could emit command and receive response on a existing opened session and also preverve hight avaibility of my system ?
The final solution would be something like that :
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't your mediator then become a single point of failure?  i.e. if your mediator box crashes, your system becomes inaccessible even if all the BE servers are working.   Perhaps a better solution is to have your client connect to multiple servers (either at the same time, or give it the necessary smarts to connect to a different server if/when the first connection stops working)

Comment: Yes you are right : in fact I do not know how to implement this mediator : I need a way to put in place some kind of port forwarding so that client1 and client2 could be seen as a unique client able send command and receive response from my BEserver on the same connected socket an as you say I need the mediator to be on at less 2 box... But I do not know if it exists something like that... But you are right , this is missing in my schema but the client1 and client2 are also able right now to talk to the two BEservices and establish a session with either : an there is no SPOF for th e moment.